# Reading Reponses SMS using SNS AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns, boto

I'm using AWS SNS service and I'm able to sent sms using that service, I was wondering if there is any way that I can read responses for my SNS SMS sent?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what responses you want to read ? Can you also share code of what you have achieved till now

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported within the SNS product. You can achieve this within AWS by using [Pinpoint two-way messaging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-sms-two-way.html) and use the same phone number to deliver SMS from using SNS.